# Implementing a mobile only screen on a website that prompts the user to reopen the link from a desktop device

Tags: css, mobile-website

I have been creating a website using Cargo Collective (CSS) and need to publish my website before I will have had time to optimise it for mobile use.

I am looking to add a prompt that will appear when the site is visit from a mobile device. This will tell any visitors that open the link from a mobile device to instead visit the website from a desktop or laptop.

Alternatively, if I were able to force the site to only load in the desktop version, even on mobile sites, this would be okay for now. Cargo collective automatically implements a mobile optimised version which I cannot seem to turn off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use @media in the CSS, however I built the website using the cargo designer, not by writing the code myself, so I am struggling to identify how to target different elements of the design.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a custom element with fixed position that wraps the entire screen on the desired resolutions and requests the user to use a larger screen. You just need to add the class to an element and it'll do.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* Optional rules. */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: #000;
  background-color: tomato;
  /* Will be displayed in the center of the element. */
  content: "Please use a larger screen with atleast 768 pixels of width.";
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, just to clarify, how exactly do I go about adding the class to the element? Sorry I am very new to CSS!

Comment: @FinnHull it really does depend on how cargo works, something I don't have any experience with. But the general HTML rule is to add the class to the element this way:
`<element class="wrapper""></element>`